# six months record of every account number in pyspark

Tags: pyspark

I have tried rank function but it gives results in numbers which goes beyond 180 days.

This is the result I am getting but I do not want this result this is wrong it is giving transaction beyond 180 days

```
window = Window.partitionBy(df3['acctno']).orderBy(df3['trans_date'])

df3.select('*', rank().over(window).alias('rank')) \
  .filter(col('rank') <= 180) \
  .show(500)
```

{    |year|month|day|date|   txnrefid|        acc|branch|channel|rank|
+----+-----+---+-----------+-----------+--------------+----------+-----------+----+
|2020|    2|  6| 2020-02-06|  1234abcd6| 2074-556-1111|      6666|        CBS|   1|
|2020|    2|  7| 2020-02-07|  1234abcd7| 2074-556-1111|      6666|        CBS|   2|
|2020|    2|  8| 2020-02-08|  1234abcd8| 2074-556-1111|      6666|        CBS|   3|
|2020|    2|  9| 2020-02-09|  1234abcd9| 2074-556-1111|      6666|        CBS|   4|

But I want like this

{|year|month|day|date|   txnrefid|        acc|branch|channel|rank|

```
|2020|    2|  6| 2020-02-06|  1234abcd6| 2074-556-1111|      6666|        CBS|   1|
|2020|    2|  7| 2020-02-07|  1234abcd7| 2074-556-1111|      6666|        CBS|   2|
|2020|    2|  8| 2020-02-08|  1234abcd8| 2074-556-1111|      6666|        CBS|   3|
|2020|    2|  9| 2020-02-09|  1234abcd9| 2074-556-1111|      6666|
```

---

}

Comment: please give an example of what you want, not what you do not want ...

Comment: Sure, I will tell you the output that I want.

Comment: At the point when you made edits to the question which invalidated one or more answers, the correct course of action was to instead create a new question. Editing Questions to improve them (e.g. clarification, adding additional information, etc.) *is encouraged*. However, editing a Question to change it into a different question which results in invalidating one or more Answers, is against Stack Exchange policy (even when your original question wasn't what you intended). Normally, any user with edit privileges should revert such edits.

Comment: In this case, given that you've received a new answer from the same user, it appears that the least harm is done by leaving the question as it currently is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you edited your question, here is a new answer that use a different approach.
The idea is to get for each account number the min date, compute the limite date (min date + 180 days) then remove all the lines that are older.

```py
df.count() # I used your sample data, so 60 lines
> 60

w = Window.partitionBy(df["acctno"])
df = df.withColumn("min_date", F.min(F.col("trans_date").cast("date")).over(w))
df = df.where(
    F.col("trans_date").cast("date")
    <= F.date_add(  # Use F.date_add to add days or F.add_months to add month.
        F.col("min_date"), 180
    )
).drop("min_date")

df.count() # Final dataframe limited to 180 days, nothing older than 2020-08-04
> 54
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and efforts this is what I was expecting. You have helped me. I accept this answer.

Answer (score 0):

if you want the first 6 month, then you should use fields "year" and "month", not "trans_date".

something like `window = Window.partitionBy(df3['acctno']).orderBy(df3['year'], df3['month'])` should give you better results.

Then you filter on `rank <= 6`

```py
df3.select("*", dense_rank().over(window).alias("rank")).filter(col("rank") <= 6).show(500)
```

---

**EDIT**: You need to use a `dense_rank`

Comment: I meant first 6 months transaction of every account for example an account will have transaction starting from month 3 so in that case I want transaction from 3 to 9 months i.e march to sept and that will be considered as first 6 months transaction for that account

Comment: @flamboyantperson i think my code does what you need. What in my code is wrong with what you expect?

Comment: your answer is not giving full results it is giving only few records in the output and only from month 1

Comment: @flamboyantperson are you sure you're not misinterpreting the output because of the `show`? If you want all your lines, use `collect`

Comment: I have tried that too. I have updated my question output and desired output dataframe result

Comment: @flamboyantperson you need to use a `dense_rank`. I updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the help it's very close to my answer but in some scenario it is not working. I have modified my question to involve that scenario so your answer will be complete. The modification is instead of 6 months I want 180 days records from the start day. Can you please help??

Comment: @flamboyantperson Please, next time, be more precise in your question to add every possible scenario.

Comment: Yes sure, sorry it was my first time on stack overflow I did not even know how to paste the data frame. I am really thankful for your reply and for being polite. Looking forward to a solution from you.